# Calculating the rank of two given matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I read somewhere that the rank of a matrix is the number of its nonzero rows or columns after Gaussian elimination. In the following matrices, how should I know Gaussian elimination is done? They are not lower or upper triangular, is the lower/upper triangular form only for square matrices? Is the following numbers correct as the rank of matrices that I calculated according to nonzero rows/columns rule?

$$
T_1=  \begin{bmatrix}
    X & X & X & X\\
    0 & X & X & X\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Here $m<n$ and $\text{rank}(A)=2<m$

$$
T_1=  \begin{bmatrix}
    X & X & X \\
    0 & X & X \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 &  0& 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Here $m>n$ and $\text{rank}(A)=2<n$

Answer (score 1):

"After Gaussian elimination" implies in [row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).

- All zero rows are at the bottom.
- The leading entry in a row is always strictly to the right of the leading entry of the row above.

The *rank* is the number of non-zero rows (or number of leading entries) in row echelon form.

E.g. highlighting the leading entries, the matrices
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue}{5} & 2 & 21 & 4 \\
0 & \color{blue}{-4} & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ and }
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \color{blue}{300} & 3 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{-5} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
are in row echelon form and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \color{blue}{-4} & 2 & 3 \\
\color{blue}{5} & 2 & 21 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix},\
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue}{5} & 2 & 21 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \color{blue}{-4} & 2 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ and }
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \color{blue}{300} & 3 & 3 \\
0 & \color{blue}{300} & 3 & 3 \\
0 & \color{blue}{300} & 3 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{-5} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
are not in row echelon form.  These matrices still have a rank, but we still have some row operations to do to get them into row echelon form.

In regards to the other parts:

- So the specified ranks are correct if the $X$s represent a "wildcard" that can only take on non-zero values.  If the $X$s may be zero, the rank could be less than $2$.
- [Upper triangular and lower triangular matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) refer to square matrices.  But we can still have upper triangular matrices that are not in row echelon form, e.g.:
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 0 & \color{blue} 1 \\
  0 & \color{blue} 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  so this is not the right condition anyway.  (Although, if a matrix is in row echelon form, we must have $0$s below the main diagonal.)